# Can I display some documents in my browser and others using their native applications?

Tags: 2010, document-library, sharepoint-foundation

I'm using SP Foundation 2010, with severly limited development permissions. I'm operating as a site Owner in a user area, so access to Designer, Visual Studio, etc. is limited and I'm looking for solutions that can be accomplished with those constraints in mind.

We have a document library of about 2000 documents used by our help desk. About 95% of these documents are html and the remaining are PDFs, Word, Excel or PowerPoint.

When users select these documents from the list, I want the HTML to open in the browser, but all other documents to open in Acrobat, Word, Excel, PowerPoint, etc. The only parameter I can find is in Doc Library > adv settings, where I can choose to open docs in the browser or not. with that box, I can get them to open in the browser window or get prompted to download the file to the local desktop...which I defintely want to avoid. Hovever I can't seem to apply this to rule differently to documents in the same library.

Suggestions on how to do this? Is there some way i can drive that with document metadata, or do I need to put HTML in one library, and all non-HTML in another, and assign separate "open file" behaviors for each library?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this [question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/114808/sp2013-open-pdf-files-in-a-new-window)

The code posted was for PDFs I just used it on my site and it works well all you would need to do is modify the code below from .pdf to what ever extension you want.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("a[href$='.pdf']").removeAttr('onclick').attr("target","_blank");
   });
</script>
```

And just place it in a Script editor web part on the page. The script editor is located here:

[image]

Be sure that your document library is set to open in client by default.