# SP2013 open pdf files in a new window

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, pdf

I am using sp2013. I have a document library with pdf files. When I click on the pdf file it opens directly in the same window.

How can I make it possible the pdf file opens in a new window?

In Central Admin I have on my webapplication the option "Browser File Handling" set on permissive.

Answer (score 3):

This is working:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("a[href$='.pdf']").removeAttr('onclick').attr("target","_blank");
   });
</script>
```

Comment: this works like a charm :)

Comment: just to add a note: unfortunately this script does not work for .pdf within a Document Library :( - shame really. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

In a content editor web part source editing, you add the following script:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("SetTargetBlank('/InsertListNameHere/')");

    function SetTargetBlank(ToFindInLink)
    {
      // Get the collection of <a> tags
      var aAllLinks = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

      // For each <a> tags, 
      for(var i=0;i<aAllLinks.length;i++)
      {
         var oA = aAllLinks[i];
         var sHREF = oA.attributes["href"].value.toLowerCase();

         // If href value contains paramter
         if(sHREF.indexOf(ToFindInLink.toLowerCase()) > 0)
            oA.attributes["target"].value = "_blank";
      }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I can see the javascript is looping into all ahrefs. When it try to set the target it gives me this error: Unable to set property 'value' of undefined or null reference

Answer (score 0):

You can get this using the Content Editor Webpart with Javascript coding...

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">



_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("OpenPDFInNewWindow()"); 



function OpenPDFInNewWindow() 

{ 

var aAllLinks = document.links; 

for(var i=0;i<aAllLinks.length;i++) 

{ 

var oA = aAllLinks[i]; 

var sHREF = oA.href.toLowerCase(); 



if(sHREF.indexOf(".jpg") > 0 

sHREF.indexOf(".pdf") > 0) 

{ 

oA.onclick=function() 

{ 

var w=window.open(this.href,'_blank',''); 

if(w) { 

w.focus(); 

return false 

}; 

return true; 

} 

} 

} 

} </script>
```

[Open Sharepoint document Library PDF files in New window](http://satishchiluka.blogspot.com/2013/03/open-sharepoint-document-library-pdf.html)

Also check this answer from MSDN forum.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/9e76f4f7-47d5-4bdf-8829-c024a1aed55e/pdf-files-wont-open-in-new-window-in-another-environment?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy

Comment: I copied this code and past it in a content editor webpart on the document library page (https://aintranet.myCompany.com/MyListName/Forms/AllItems.aspx). It stil not working. Using IE11 compatibility mode.

Comment: IE 32 bit or 64 bit? so it did not work with/out of Compatibility mode?

Comment: 64 bit, also without compatibility mode it is not working. Is this script also tested on sp2013?

Answer (score 0):

This is the behavior you find it in IE11. IE10 it works fine.

Comment: Ok thats clear, but is there some workaround to  make it possible?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in SharePoint 2013 document library with grouping 
http://www.benramey.com/2011/04/25/opening-all-sharepoint-2010-documents-in-a-new-window/

Answer (score 0):

This is a web app wide setting or a doc lib specific etting. In Central Admin (or through Powershell), change file handling for a web application:

https://community.colligo.com/entries/23392255-How-can-I-enable-the-option-to-open-a-file-from-SharePoint-

```
$web  = Get-SPWeb http://yourspweburl
#Get Document Library
$docLib = $web.lists["Your Document Library Title"]
#If you need to change it from Strict to Permissive
$docLib.BrowserFileHandling = "Permissive"
$docLib.Update()
```

Answer (score 0):

The script copied from Ben's Blog:
http://www.benramey.com/2011/04/25/opening-all-sharepoint-2010-documents-in-a-new-window/

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(
        function () {
            // has to be on an interval for grouped doc libraries
            // where the actual links are loaded only once a group
            // is expanded
            setInterval(
                function () {
                    $("a[onclick*=’return DispEx’][target!=’_blank’]")
                        .attr("target", "_blank")
                        .removeAttr("onclick");

                    // document type icons
                    $("td.ms-vb-icon>img[onclick]:not([documentUrl])")
                        .click(function (e) {
                            window.open($(this).attr("documentUrl"), "_blank");
                            e.stopPropagation();
                            e.preventDefault();
                            return false;
                        })
                        .each(function () {
                            $(this).attr(
                                "documentUrl",
                                $.trim(String($(this).attr("onclick"))
                                    .split("=")[1]
                                    .replace(/["'{}]/g, "")
                                    .split(";")[0])
                                );
                            this.onclick = null;
                        });
                    },
                    500
            );
        }
    );
    </script>
```

This works even with SP2013 Document Library but the only drawback is that it opens any (all) the documents in a new _blank browser.

**How to make it open .PDF only in a new browser??**

> http://www.keremozen.com/category/sharepoint/page/5/

It is done by adding the `[href*='.pdf']`

```
$("a[onclick*='return DispEx'][target!='_blank'][href*='.pdf']")
```

I know the topic is over 2yrs old but this works like a charm and might come handy to somebody else who is a newbie :)