# Opening document library files in popup or new window

Tags: 2010, 2013, document-library, document, popup

Is there any easy way to open the document library files in a new window or popup depending on the file types?

e.g. `PDF` - In Adobe reader (currently opens in IE)

Image file (currently opens in IE)

Answer (score 2):

I used the below to do this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.s4-ba a').attr("target", "_blank")
$('.s4-ba a').removeAttr("onclick");
});</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's working for me in SharePoint 2013

http://www.benramey.com/2011/04/25/opening-all-sharepoint-2010-documents-in-a-new-window/

Insert a content editor and add the following code,

```
$(document).ready(
function () {
    // has to be on an interval for grouped doc libraries
    // where the actual links are loaded only once a group
    // is expanded
    setInterval(
        function () {
            $("a[onclick*=’return DispEx’][target!=’_blank’]")
                .attr("target", "_blank")
                .removeAttr("onclick");

            // document type icons
            $("td.ms-vb-icon>img[onclick]:not([documentUrl])")
                .click(function (e) {
                    window.open($(this).attr("documentUrl"), "_blank");
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                })
                .each(function () {
                    $(this).attr(
                        "documentUrl",
                        $.trim(String($(this).attr("onclick"))
                            .split("=")[1]
                            .replace(/["'{}]/g, "")
                            .split(";")[0])
                        );
                    this.onclick = null;
                });
            },
            500
    );
}
```

);

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

It can be possible to open files in new window in Internet Explorer itself, have to modify little bit XSLT (as need to add `_blank='true'`) in `ListViewWebpart` embedded in list view page itself.

Yes, design mode is not available. I am not saying to open design mode.

1. Open library in sharepoint designer.
2. Click 'Advanced' in Home tab.
3. Markup will be visible, select the `XsltListVievWebpart` tag from start to end
4. By doing 3) step, a new tab appear named "List View tools".
5. Within that tab go to Design options and click 'customize xslt'
6. Check xsl will now render, search by `Verifyhref`
7. Add `_blank='true'` there.

After the operation performed from screenshot, perform step 6 and 7 and do preview the page in browser from SPD itself.

Here are some screenshots:

First part
[image: First PArt]

Second part[image: Second part]

Comment: what about SharePoint 2013 i don't get control over view?

Comment: SharePoint 2013 has given us a property JSlink to modify our view as we need to do so.
But in that case you to written a bit javascript decorating your view in html and giving link to document as anchor tag with '_blank' property.
Else than I think, xslt is the only way with SharePoint designer

Comment: not getting the exact property to place "_blank". let me know if you have any

Comment: Do one thing instead of that, go to document library settings page> Advanced settings>Opening Document in Browser>Choose-Open in client application

Comment: yes tried it, it doesn't work

Comment: Edit library in SharePoint designer (Advance mode)> Select advanced mode from Home tab> Select Xsltlistview webpart tag in designer> List view tools tab will be enabled > Within that tab go to Design option > Click customize xslt> serach xsl by term "Verifyhref"> A anchor link will appear, add _blank='true' there . F
For example: <a onfocus="OnLink(this)" href="{$thisNode/@FileRef}" _blank="true" onmousedown="return VerifyHref(this,event,'{$XmlDefinition/List/@DefaultItemOpen}','{$thisNode/@HTML_x0020_File_x0020_Type.File_x0020_Type.mapcon}','{$thisNode/@serverurl.progid}')"

Comment: this setting is for SharePoint 2010 designer, right?

Comment: No, possible in both Share 2013 and SharePoint 2010 designer

Comment: Design mode is not available in Designer 2013.

Comment: Yes, designer mode is not visible in SP-2013. Please do see my comments above in answer post as edited.

Comment: not able to get the things in SP designer 2013, if you could share some screenshots for understanding

Comment: try the part as mentioned in screenshot

Comment: tried that. but i am not able to get List View Tools anyhow.

Comment: even after checking "Server Rendering" checkbox in webpart properties!

Comment: yes after selecting "Server Rendering" also. not sure what is the problm here :(

Answer (score 0):

This is a web app wide setting or a doc lib specific etting. In Central Admin (or through Powershell), change file handling for a web application:

https://community.colligo.com/entries/23392255-How-can-I-enable-the-option-to-open-a-file-from-SharePoint-

```
$web  = Get-SPWeb http://yourspweburl
#Get Document Library
$docLib = $web.lists["Your Document Library Title"]
#If you need to change it from Strict to Permissive
$docLib.BrowserFileHandling = "Permissive"
$docLib.Update()
```

Comment: Please don't add the exact same answer to this question, as you did on [this one](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/114808/sp2013-open-pdf-files-in-a-new-window/171283#171283). Instead, try to specify your answer further to make it a better of this specific question. Thank You!