# SharePoint 2013 Document Library - Open pdf in New Tab

Tags: 2013, javascript, document-library, document, pdf

I am using the code snippet below to ensure pdf files in a SharePoint 2013 document library open in a new tab.

This code works fine until files in the document library are grouped. Can someone please help tweak the code so I can ensure that pdf files in a 'grouped' library also open in new tabs?

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("a[href$='.pdf']").removeAttr("onclick");
            $("a[href$='.pdf']").removeAttr("onmousedown");
            $("a[href$='.pdf']").attr("target", "_blank");       
        });
    </script>
```

Please note that I am specifically looking for a code snippet that will ensure pdf documents will open in a new tab when the items in the document library are **grouped**. The code I have is already working for pdf documents in non-grouped libraries.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this as posted [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/115922/opening-document-library-files-in-popup-or-new-window)

```
$(document).ready(
function () {
    // has to be on an interval for grouped doc libraries
    // where the actual links are loaded only once a group
    // is expanded
    setInterval(
        function () {
            $("a[onclick*=’return DispEx’][target!=’_blank’]")
                .attr("target", "_blank")
                .removeAttr("onclick");

            // document type icons
            $("td.ms-vb-icon>img[onclick]:not([documentUrl])")
                .click(function (e) {
                    window.open($(this).attr("documentUrl"), "_blank");
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                })
                .each(function () {
                    $(this).attr(
                        "documentUrl",
                        $.trim(String($(this).attr("onclick"))
                            .split("=")[1]
                            .replace(/["'{}]/g, "")
                            .split(";")[0])
                        );
                    this.onclick = null;
                });
            },
            500
    );
}
);
```

Comment: Hi Sorhyu. Thanks for taking the time to reply. I've tried the suggested code but pdf files are still opening in the browser and not in a new tab unfortunately.